# re.findall multiline python

Tags: python, regex

re.findall with re.M is not finding the multiline i'm trying to search for

I am trying to extract all multiline strings matching a pattern from a file

Example from file `book.txt`:

```
Title: Le Morte D'Arthur, Volume I (of II)
       King Arthur and of his Noble Knights of the Round Table

Author: Thomas Malory

Editor: William Caxton

Release Date: March, 1998  [Etext #1251]
Posting Date: November 6, 2009

Language: English

Title: Pride and Prejudice

Author: Jane Austen

Posting Date: August 26, 2008 [EBook #1342]
Release Date: June, 1998
Last Updated: October 17, 2016

Language: English
```

The following code only returns the first line `Le Morte D'Arthur, Volume I (of II)`

```
re.findall('^Title:\s(.+)$', book, re.M)
```

I am expecting the output to be

`[' Le Morte D'Arthur, Volume I (of II)\n      King Arthur and of his Noble Knights of the Round Table', ' Pride and Prejudice']`

To clarify,
- The second line is optional, its there in some files and not there in others. Also there's more text after the second line that I don't want to read.
- Using `re.findall(r'Title: (.+\n.+)$', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)` works but fails if the second line is just blank.
- I'm running python3.7.
- I'm converting a txt file to a string and then running `re` on the str.
- The following don't work either:
`re.findall(r'^Title:\s(.+)$', text, re.S)`
`re.findall(r'^Title:\s(.+)$', text, re.DOTALL)`

Comment: The dot doesn't match the newline by default, add `re.S`

Comment: Try: `re.findall(r'Title: (.+\n.+)$', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: as in one of the answers below, `re.DOTALL` would be the simple way to achieve your goal

Comment: To answer your question please add the following details: 1) how are you getting the data - reading from file? Add this code, 2) What are other examples? How do you describe the pattern in words? Hoew to know when the matching should stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe this expression,

```
(?<=Title:\s)(.*?)\s*(?=Author)
```

might be close to what might be desired to be designed.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yI148n/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"(?<=Title:\s)(.*?)\s*(?=Author)"

test_str = ("Title: Le Morte D'Arthur, Volume I (of II)\n"
    "       King Arthur and of his Noble Knights of the Round Table\n\n"
    "Title: Le Morte D'Arthur, Volume I (of II)\n"
    "       King Arthur and of his Noble Knights of the Round Table")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.DOTALL))
```

#### Output

```
["Le Morte D'Arthur, Volume I (of II)\n       King Arthur and of his Noble Knights of the Round Table\n\n", "Le Morte D'Arthur, Volume I (of II)\n       King Arthur and of his Noble Knights of the Round Table"]
```

Comment: This works but it ends up reading all the lines, i just want it to read one line after the `Title:` line

Comment: I added enough data that should suffice for the demo and also update my OP to reflect the same.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I wasn't sure if `author` always came after `title` so I modified it a little and it works, [here](https://regex101.com/r/yI148n/2)

Answer (score 2):

You can use your regex with the `DOTALL` flag for allowing your `.` to match the newline char :

```
re.findall('^Title:\s(.+)$', book, re.DOTALL)
```

output :

```
Le Morte D'Arthur, Volume I (of II)\n       King Arthur and of his Noble Knights of the Round Table
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, not sure why, i'm running python3.7